# Greensock doesn't put elements back to their place

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am using greensock library to animate some elements and then revert the animation to the old position. After I do the revert, my elements don't return to the old location.

Below is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  tweenObject();

  function tweenObject() {
    var line = new TimelineLite({paused:true});
    line.add(TweenLite.to($("#bar"), 1, {
      x: 300,
      y: 100
    }));
    line.add(TweenLite.to($("#html"), 1, {
      x: -300,
      y: 100
    }));
     line.add(TweenLite.to($("#bar"), 1, {
      x: -300,
      y: -100
    }));
    line.add(TweenLite.to($("#html"), 1, {
      x: 300,
      y: -100
    }));
$("#play").click(function(){
  line.play();
})
    $("#pause").click(function(){
  line.pause();
})
  
  }

  
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
img{
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TimelineLite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenLite.min.js"></script>

<div id="firstDiv">
<img src="https://greensock.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/robust.png" id="bar"/>
</div>
<div id="secondDiv">
<img src="https://greensock.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/compatible.png" id="html"/>
  <p id="myText"> this is any text here</p>
</div>  


<input type="button" id="play" value="play" />
<input type="button" id="pause" value="pause" />
```

When clicking on play in my example, it should relocate the 2 images, and then put them back to their old location, which is not happening here.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: the values assigned are not relative and are actually absolute. try `x: '-=300'` and such for relative values. **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/hss6mv40/)**.

Comment: How are they not relative? How do I make an element move in a way relative to its current position using greensock?

Comment: you can take a look at the fiddle I posted in my comment. It contains a couple of approaches you can take here.